# Change Search display for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-taxonomy

I want the search to not search for custom post type "mitgliederbereich" when on other pages, and when you are on the "mitgliederbereich" page, that only "mitgliederbereich" posts should appear in search. How can I achieve this?
Here is my functions.php code for the function.

```
function mitgliederbereich_filter_search($query) {

   global $post;

   if ($post->post_type == "mitgliederbereich") {

    if (!$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post'));
    }
    return $query;

   } else {

      if (!$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('mitgliederbereich'));
    }
    return $query;

   }

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'mitgliederbereich_filter_search');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
function mitgliederbereich_filter_search($query) {
  global $post;
  global $wp_post_types;
  if ($post->post_type == "mitgliederbereich") {
      $wp_post_types['mitgliederbereich']->exclude_from_search = false;
  } else {
      $wp_post_types['mitgliederbereich']->exclude_from_search = true;
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'mitgliederbereich_filter_search');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you :)